# how to insert multiple data based on checkbox selection in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am stuck with Laravel multiple insertion below is my code

blade.php file

```
     @foreach($processess as $process)                         
            <tr>                   
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_process[]" class="select_process" value="{{$process->id}}"></td>                           
                <td>{{$count}}</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" class="product_id" value="{{$process->product_id}}">{{$process->product_name}}</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="product_stock_id[]" class="product_stock_id" value="{{$process->id}}">{{$process->product_name}} {{$process->id}}</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="purchase_date[]" class="purchase_date" value="{{$process->purchase_date}}">{{date('M j Y',strtotime($process->purchase_date))}}</td>  
               <td><input type="hidden" name="expire_date[]" class="expire_date" value="{{$process->expire_date}}">{{date('M j Y',strtotime($process->expire_date))}}</td>                          
                <td>
                <td>{{$process->status ? $process->status : '-'}}</td>                                           
          </tr>           
        @endforeach
```

This is my controller  file

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($data['select_process']); $i++) {
            
            DB::table('processing_data')
                    ->insert([
                        'product_id' => $data['product_id'][$i],
                        'product_stock_id' => $data['product_stock_id'][$i],
                        'purchase_date' => $data['purchase_date'][$i],
                        'expire_date' => $data['expire_date'][$i],
                        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
                    ]);
        }
```

when user select the checkbox I want to store the selected checkbox row into database. I got the solution for multiple checkboxes when user select all the checkboxes the it will store all data properly but when user select last row of table it stores the value of first row. I need to store the selected checkbox value

Comment: Please look your on request's post data and will you see what happened, because of checkbox sensd data when checked and you expect that send whole data as array, when you post data but each input element has a value and represent as array on php but check boxes doesnt have a value if not checked and your array doesn't work what you expected so you should post data just checked structure or hidden input[text] when you checked/unchecked and set it value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need define `$process->id` to the hidden data, add it to `inputname[{{$process->id}}]` like below:

```
@foreach($processess as $process)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_process[{{$process->id}}]" class="select_process" value="{{$process->id}}"></td>
        <td>{{$count}}</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="product_id[{{$process->id}}]" class="product_id" value="{{$process->product_id}}">{{$process->product_name}}</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="product_stock_id[{{$process->id}}]" class="product_stock_id" value="{{$process->id}}">{{$process->product_name}} {{$process->id}}</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="purchase_date[{{$process->id}}]" class="purchase_date"
                   value="{{$process->purchase_date}}">{{date('M j Y',strtotime($process->purchase_date))}}</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="expire_date[{{$process->id}}]" class="expire_date" value="{{$process->expire_date}}">{{date('M j Y',strtotime($process->expire_date))}}
        </td>
        <td>
        <td>{{$process->status ? $process->status : '-'}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Then insert by process id like below:

```
foreach(request()->select_process as $selected) {
    DB::table('processing_data')
        ->insert(
            [
                'product_id'       => $data['product_id'][$selected],
                'product_stock_id' => $data['product_stock_id'][$selected],
                'purchase_date'    => $data['purchase_date'][$selected],
                'expire_date'      => $data['expire_date'][$selected],
                'created_at'       => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
            ]
        );
}
```

I assumed `$data` is `request()->all()`.

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad it works thank you so much appreciate.